# CSS not being applied to generated PDF

Tags: java, css, flying-saucer

**Problem**

I use Flying-saucer to generate a PDF from an HTML file.

The PDF is correctly generated but the CSS is not applied to it.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="print" type="text/css" href="C:/Users/f_antbar/Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Gest_saisie/css/printPDF.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="background-color:white; width:100%"><img src="C:/Users/f_antbar/Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Gest_saisie/img/logo_50.jpg"/></div>
  <div id="corps">...
```

**Generator**

```
try {
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(context.getRealPath("documents")+"/print/test.pdf");
    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    renderer.setDocument(new File(context.getRealPath("documents")+"/print/test.html"));
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(os);
    os.close();
    System.out.println("PDF created");
} catch (Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The CSS is validated by the W3C validator, the path is correct since I used it with only iText but since iText doesn't support much CSS I wanted to try with flying-saucer.

**Configuration**

I'm working with

- Struts2
- iText 2.1.7
- flying-saucer-core-9.0.7
- flying-saucer-pdf-9.0.7

Answer (score 0):

****As I don't have access to adding comment, it is mentioned in Answer section

Hi,

The href links mentioned for stylesheet might not be accessbile when executing the code. Make it available over a URL and edit the html with respective URLS. (make sure it is accessible to the server where the code is executing).

For a verification try to insert entire stylesheet code into the `<style></style>` tags and execute.